# notifyDatasetChanged() id not working

Tags: android, database, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have to fetch the data from the database and populate it into the ListView. But everytime  I am running it, it adds the data into the previous data...

for example.. 
1st run:- 
A
B
C

2nd run:- 
A
B
C
A
B
C

and so on..

Here is my code I am using where I am using NotifyDatasetChanged()

```
List<Tag> allTags = db.getAllTags();
    for (Tag tag : allTags) {


        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);


        arraylist=new ArrayAdapter<Tag>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allTags);
        lv1.setAdapter(arraylist);



        Log.d("Tag Name", tag.getTagName());


        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    arraylist.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }
        });
    }
```

I have searched many links, applied their answers in my code, But nothing is changed.

Comment: Why you are setting the adapter inside for loop?

Comment: For every Tag in your data base, you are creating an adapter and setting it on your ListView. This is not correct. You should only create the adapter and set it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your adapter using `allTags`, so whenever you are changing the value of `allTags` by adding or removing more elements and then immediately calling `notifyDataSetChange()` it will reflect the changes in the adapter. What I can see here in your code is that inside `OnItemClickListener` you are not modifying your `allTags` hence calling `notifyDataSetChanged` is not effective.